Deadlock when redirecting Windows `cmd.exe` I/O using pipes
I am trying to create redirect io from my program in c to a cmd.exe process and using pipes for handling the io to process the input command by my program and return back the output.
And I want to make cmd.exe process run in the background, (I know I could use cmd /C <command> each time I need to process something).

And here is my approach for now.

Create two pipes, One for stdin and the other for stdout.
Create the cmd.exe as a child process using CreateProcess and use STARTUPINFO to set the process stdin and stdout to the write end of the stdin pipe and the read end of the stdout pipe.
Input a command to the write end of the stdin pipe using WriteFile.
Read the output from the read end of the stdout pipe using ReadFile.

And here is code in my head for now.
// NOTE: This code is for demonstration purposes only. 
// It is not optimized for performance or error handling.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  BOOL success = FALSE;

  PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo = {};
  STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = {};
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SecurityAttr = {};


  HANDLE StdinRead, StdinWrite;
  HANDLE StdoutRead, StdoutWrite;

  CHAR buffer[1024] = "echo HelloWorld!\n";
  DWORD WrittenBytes = 0;
  DWORD ReadedBytes = 0;

  SecurityAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

  if (!CreatePipe(&StdinRead, &StdinWrite, &SecurityAttr, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Stdin pipe creation failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!SetHandleInformation(StdinWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Stdin SetHandleInformation failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!CreatePipe(&StdoutRead, &StdoutWrite, &SecurityAttr, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Stdout pipe creation failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!SetHandleInformation(StdoutRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Stdout SetHandleInformation failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  StartupInfo.hStdError = StdoutWrite;
  StartupInfo.hStdOutput = StdoutWrite;
  StartupInfo.hStdInput = StdinRead;
  StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

  success =
      CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
                    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo);

  if (!success) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] CreateProcess failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  CloseHandle(StdoutWrite);
  CloseHandle(StdinRead);

  success = WriteFile(StdinWrite, buffer, strlen(buffer), &WrittenBytes, NULL);

  if (!success) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] WriteFile failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (TRUE) {
    success = ReadFile(StdoutRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &ReadedBytes, NULL);
    if (!success) {
      fprintf(stderr, "[!] ReadFile failed.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    buffer[ReadedBytes] = 0;
    printf("[*] ReadFile output: %s\n", buffer);
  }

  return 0;
}

The problem is that the ReadFile call generates a deadlock when the cmd.exe is done writing to the stdout and there is no more data to read.
The output of the program is something like that.
[*] ReadFile output: Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043

[*] ReadFile output:
D:cmd_stdio>HelloWorld!

D:cmd_stdio>^C

I have to CTRL+C to close.
In Microsoft Article about Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading.

In my case, I don't want to close the stdin pipe write handle.
I got an idea to solve this issue (but I don't like it) by appending an end flag and check the end of the buffer for that flag
// NOTE: This code is for demonstration purposes only. 
// It is not optimized for performance or error handling.


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define END_FLAG "[cmd is done]"

int main() {

  // same code as above

  strcat(buffer, "; echo " END_FLAG "\n");
  success = WriteFile(StdinWrite, buffer, strlen(buffer), &WrittenBytes, NULL);
  ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  if (!success) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] WriteFile failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (TRUE) {
    success = ReadFile(StdoutRead, buffer + index, sizeof(buffer) - index,
                       &ReadedBytes, NULL);
    if (!success) {
      fprintf(stderr, "[!] ReadFile failed.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    buffer[index + ReadedBytes] = 0;
    index += ReadedBytes;

    if (strstr(buffer, END_FLAG) != NULL) {
      printf("[*] Command execution completed.\n");
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("[*] ReadFile output: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
// (you could create a 64-bit flag and XOR it with the last 8bytes of written data to the buffer, this code only for explaining my point)

My Question is: Is there is a better way to know if the child process is done writing and ready to receive input or no?

At first - for what you need cmd ? You not need it. Run direct exe, which you need. And you not need 2 pipes pair. Create only one. With asynchronous server end ( use it in own process) and synchronous client end ( pass as std handles to child process) . With asynchronous i/o you never got deadlock

I'm trying to write a small terminal emulator, using Open-Gl to render text, and adding more features.

My problem is not laying primarily in the deadlock, my problem is how can i know when the cmd or powershel process is done  executing the command entered so a user can start writing. so the user can input more data.

In most case cmd not need, and possibly direct run target program. However really problem not in this. If use asynchronous i/o was no any problems here

"I'm trying to write a small terminal emulator" - See Creating a Pseudoconsole session. That said, OpenGL is the wrong API when uncompromised performance is the end goal.

to know if the child process is done writing and ready to receive input or no - this is wrong question. you not need know first and can write to pipe at any time. read - always  (after read completed just begin new read until error) and write at any time, when you need do this

The way that the Microsoft article (and your code) is setup, synchronous pipes and synchronous IO are being used. The stdout pipe stays open until the child process terminates, thus ending a blocked ReadFile.
In the case of cmd without /C, that happens when the user closes the console window, but you are not creating a console window, so ReadFile blocks indefinitely (unless you send another command) since the pipe never closes (unless someone kills the cmd process).
So, either use cmd /C so the process ends when the command is finished, or use an asynchronous pipe so you can put a timeout on the pipe reading.
